# Is there an "OR" condition in jquery selector strings?

Tags: jquery

I would like to test an element object to see if it has either "classA" *or* "classB". For example, a click() event has returned an element in the event's `target` property. I want to test this element to see if has either of those two classes.

```
$("#mybutton").click(function($event) {
  var $el = $($event.target);
  if($el.is(".classA") || $el.is(".classB")) {
    // Can I do the above with 1 selector instead of two separate ones?
  }
});
```

As above, using the `is()` function, I can check for each class individually, but I'm curious if I can do it with one function call instead of two?

Comment: by the way `$($event.target)` is unnecessary, `$(this)` would do the same thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can separate the selectors with a comma:

```
if($el.is(".classA, .classB"))
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/7W9Xx/)**.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason that format was in my head as "selecting", as opposed to "testing", so I didn't try it.. but it's kind of the same thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can test if

```
if($el.is('.classA, .classB')) { ... }
```

Here is a little test case: http://jsfiddle.net/ydtv2/

Answer (score 0):

no there is not any or condition in jquery.you have to use the selectors in same statement like `$el.is(".classA, .classB")` and it can treat with this as or condition